# android : alarm not wake device up

Tags: android, alarmmanager

The following works fine when the device is not asleep, however if I turn the device off - it does not wake up at the specified time.

Did I possibly miss something? Thanks in advance for your help.

onReiceive

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {         
    WakeLocker.acquire(context);  

        pk = Integer.parseInt(intent.getExtras().get("pk").toString());     
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(context,ALERT.class);
        intent2.putExtra("pk", pk);
        intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent2);         

    WakeLocker.release();
}}
```

WakeLocker

```
public static void acquire(Context ctx) {

if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release();

PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |  PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
            PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "my tag");
    wakeLock.acquire();
}
public static void release() {
    if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release(); wakeLock = null;
}
}
```

Setalarm

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(SETALARM.this, ALARMRECEIVER.class);
    intent.putExtra("pk", pk);
    sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, pk, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),60000, sender);
```

Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the Android developers, there had been stated.

> Registered alarms are retained while the device is asleep (and can optionally wake the device up if they go off during that time), but will be cleared if it is turned off and rebooted.

So, your alarm manager has been cleared if the device is turned off.

You can refer this website. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html